# Slope plot with marginal distributions using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the slope plot below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = 1:100,
  x1 = sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = x1 + sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    2:3,
    names_to = "var",
    values_to = "val"
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val, group = id)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I want to show the distribution of x1 and x2 alongside the points. This can almost be accomplished with [the gghalves package:](https://erocoar.github.io/gghalves/)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gghalves)

df <- tibble(
  id = 1:100,
  x1 = sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = x1 + sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    2:3,
    names_to = "var",
    values_to = "val"
  )

ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val)) +
  geom_half_violin() +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But I also want to (1) complete the slope graph by connecting the points with the slope lines; and (2) flip the second violin distribution so the points are inside and the distribution is on the outside. Is it possible to accomplish both in the same plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just calculate the densities then plot them with polygons:

```r
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(x = as.numeric(factor(var))) %>%
  reframe(xval = sign(first(x) - 1.5) * 10 * density(val)$y + first(x),
          y = density(val)$x, x = first(x), .by = var) 

ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val, group = id)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_polygon(aes(xval, y, group = x), 
               fill = "orangered", alpha = 0.3, data = df2) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Allan, that's a great solution. I suppose the approach to get box plots or histograms would be totally different.

Comment: You could check out the [ggrain](https://github.com/njudd/ggrain?tab=readme-ov-file) package. It has lots of options to create plots like this, including boxplots.

Comment: One minor drawback of this solution is that the default density estimator of `density()` does a poor job on uniform data (or more generally, bounded data) --- you can see that it gives a false impression that the density goes down at the edges of `x1`, when we know the data are generated from a uniform distribution so density does not decrease smoothly at the boundary.

I'm a bit biased here, but the solution proposed by @Randy B using ggdist does not have this problem, as its default density estimator detects the boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

The package `ggdist` can do this, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggdist)

df <- tibble(
  id = 1:100,
  x1 = sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE),
  x2 = x1 + sample(1:50, 100, replace = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    2:3,
    names_to = "var",
    values_to = "val"
  ) %>% mutate(var = factor(var))

ggplot(df, aes(x = var, y = val)) +
  stat_slab(aes(scale = -1.5 + as.numeric(var))) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(group = id), alpha = 0.3)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2BdX.png)

Comment: The intent would probably be clearer if you use `stat_slab(aes(side = ifelse(var == "x1", "left", "right")))`